# In Slick grid while scrolling through columns using horizontal bar when 'toggle filter row' is enabled, the content alignment get shaky

Tags: angular, slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

I am using angular slick grid version 4.3.1 to show my list of data. If the slick grid contains more columns, while scrolling using the horizontal bar with 'toggle filter row' enabled the alignment gets a little shaky and struck, while without enabling 'toggle filter row' it goes smoothly without any issue.

**Steps to reproduce**

- Have many columns in the slick grid.
- Enable 'toggle filter row'.
- Horizontally scroll slowly through the columns, the alignment gets shaky.

**Current Behavior:** While scrolling through columns with 'toggle filter row' enabled, content alignment gets misaligned.

[Demo Gif for horizontal scrolling with toggle filter enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieoMv.gif)

**Expected Behavior:** Using the Horizontal bar, scrolling through columns with the 'toggle filter row' enabled should be the same as scrolling through columns without enabling the 'toggle filter row'.

Kindly provide the solution for this issue in the slick grid.

**Software Version**

- Angular: 13.3.9
- Angular-Slickgrid : 4.3.1
- TypeScript: 4.6.4
- Operating System: Windows 10
- Node: 14.18.3
- NPM: 6.14.8

Comment: I'm the maintainer and even though, we've noticed that in some grids, I don't know how to fix it. However it seems to be a problem/bug in Chromium browser only, I don't see this problem in Firefox so perhaps it's them to fix it

Comment: it seems that you're right in mentioning that the filters row is causing the issue, I don't see the problem when filters aren't shown (ie this [Example](https://ghiscoding.github.io/slickgrid-universal/#/example17)). I looked at UI Grid and one of them proposed to hide filters when scrolling to improve perf, perhaps that might help scroll too, I wonder if it could be done in CSS with visibility changes

Answer (score 0):

A fix was pushed to SlickGrid with this [PR](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/pull/722) which should help with this problem. It is available in Slickgrid-Universal v2.4.0 and Angular-Slickgrid v5.4.0, you would have to upgrade to get the fix